# What is the difference between indiscrete metric space and indiscrete topological space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What is the  difference  between indiscrete metric space  and indiscrete topological space?

I'm  confusing  both are  same.  I have  also read one  theorem  that  every metric space  is  Hausdorff  but  here   both  are  not  Hausdorff. This  create lot of confusion to me

Comment: A topology is not necessarily defined by a metric.

Comment: "Discrete metric" is one of the metrics that defines the discrete topology.  The indiscrete topology is (usually) not metrizable, so I do not know what an "indiscrete metric" would be.

Comment: @GEdgar u mean  Indiscrete  metric  is not exist ?

Comment: I mean: I have never heard of indiscrete metric, so you will need to provide more context for your question.

Comment: @GEdgar there is a *pseudometric* space $(X,d)$ with $d[X \times X]=\{0\}$. Its topology is indiscrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an indiscrete topological space  $X$ is metrizable then $X$ is necessarily a singleton whereas it can be any set without metrizability. Proof: Fix $x$. $B(x,r)=X$ for any $r>0$ so $d(y,x) <r$ always. Thus $y\in X$ implies $y=x$.

Comment: okss@Kavi sir  what  about  indiscrete metric space ?

Comment: What is your defintion of an indiscrete metric space. The only definition I can think of is a metric space such that the only open sets are the empty set and the whole space. I have shown that such a space is  a singleton. @jasmine

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: either a singleton or the empty space.